# To add event listeners to all the frames in a document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on something which requires me to add mouse/keyboard event listeners to the document on document load.

`document/window.addEventListener()` worked well until I came across Frameset/frames/iframes.

I did some workaround, like iterating through all the frames of frameset and added event-listeners to them.

Then I realized frames are loaded dynamically, after DOM.
So I've done something like this:

```
    bindListenersToFrame: function(element){
        var $ = domUtils.jQuery;
        $(element).ready(function(){
            if(element.tagName == "FRAMESET" || element.tagName == "BODY"){
                    for(var i=0; i < element.children.length; i++){
                            domUtils.bindListenersToFrame(element.children[i]);
                    }
            }
            if(element.tagName == "FRAME" || element.tagName == "IFRAME"){
                $('iframe').load(function(){
                    domUtils.addListener(element);
                    if(element.contentDocument.documentElement){
                            for(var i=0; i < element.contentDocument.documentElement.children.length; i++){
                                    domUtils.bindListenersToFrame(element.contentDocument.documentElement.children[i]);
                            }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
}
```

Above method is recursive in nature and domUtils is just a object with methods like "addListener".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I have not seen `framset` since the late 90s. Avoid. It's also not recommended to nest `iframes`.However, if all are hosted on the same domain, you should be able to do this (although you might want to just select with `$('iframe').each(function(){ ...find body, add event listener and repeat in this body untill there are none left... })` instead of checking every node manually.)

Comment: I am dealing with WAS, and believe me, "iframes" have been used there insanely.

Comment: @somethinghere
"$('iframe').each(function(){ ...find body, add event listener and repeat in this body untill there are none left... })" can you please elaborate this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('body').on('click','iframe',function(e) {
       console.log("clicked");
});
```

Comment: The same issue as the other answer, you aren't accounting for the iframes inside the document. They don't pass their events on to their parents, because they are iframes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest recursively checking for frames and attaching listeners. This really shouldn't be done, but it's the only way. Be aware this snippet does not work on SO due to sandboxing restrictions on snippets. I have tested it and it works locally an a server. I am also not able to find (in the limited time I have) a way around the `setTimeout` I am currently using. It feels like it gets applied before the page is loaded, but I can't see any effect from these `load` events, so for the sake of just showing how it could work, please check this:

```js
function nestedIFrameEventAttacher( iframe, event, handler ){

  const content = iframe.contentDocument || (iframe.contentWindow ? iframe.contentWindow .document : iframe);
  const body = content.querySelector( 'body' );
    
  body.addEventListener( event, handler );
  
  // I have tried attaching `load` and `DOMContentLoaded` events
  // to the `iframe` and the `body` but none of them seemed to trigger. 
  // This is therefor not guaranteed to work, but you can start from this.
  setTimeout(function(){
  
    Array.from( body.querySelectorAll( 'iframe' ) ).forEach(iframe => {

      nestedIFrameEventAttacher( iframe, event, handler );

    });
  
  }, 100);

}

const output = document.getElementById( 'output' )

nestedIFrameEventAttacher( document, 'click', function( event ){
    
    output.textContent = this.querySelector( 'h1' ).textContent;

});
```

```css
#output{ color: red; }
```

```html
<div id="output">Stealie the Dog</div>
<h1>Root</h1>
<iframe srcdoc="<html><head></head><body><h1>Second</h1><iframe srcdoc='<html><head></head><body><h1>Deeper</h2></body></html>'></iframe></body></html>" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
```

Comment: Let me check this out locally. Thanks

Comment: @shubhamwanne I also didn't test this exactly, I just hosted nested iframes with `src` instead of `srcdoc`, I just tried to make it work on Stack Overflow. It's best to just make three page, add an `<h1>` to each and nest them recursively inside each other. THen run your scripts on the top level page.

Answer (score -1):

Why not add the listener to `<body>`?

```
$('body').click(function(e) {
    console.log("clicked")
})
```

Comment: Because listeners dont propagate up through nested frames.

Comment: @somethinghere, agreed.